# Remove fragment from navigation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am using Navigation bar, in this there are 5 fragments in my "Main Activity".
My 5th fragment is Survey page, i want when survey is finished this 5th fragment will remove from my navigation bar.

My code in Main Activity:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new AFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new BFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new CFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new DFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new SurveyFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        ft.commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use fragmentstackcount for it

Comment: In 5th fragment there is button i.e. finish, when click finish button this fragment should be remove also from navigation bar.

Comment: Than you have to use viewpager for it .Please search for viewpager

Comment: @AnandSavjani can you explain further why you think viewpager would solve this ? Obviously (it's very obvious if you read the code above), the fragments are part of a navigation drawer, so viewpager just sounds like you have no idea what you are talking about ....

Comment: Because you can add or remove fragment dynamically.Thats why i recommend you for use it

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a ViewPager with an Adapter. When the survey is done you can set a boolean in the Activity and then refresh the Adapter.

The boolean will do something like this:

```
{
   if(survayNotDone) 
       adapter.add(5thFragment);
   viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

By Navigation bar you probably mean NavigationDrawer, so you could declare a callback interface:

```
public interface OnFinishCallback {
    void onFinish();
}
```

Then implement it in your activity:

```
public class MainActivity implements OnFinishCallback {
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        //remove survey item from adapter 
    }
}
```

And pass this callback into your Survey fragment which will call onFinish() method whenever it needs to finish.